# Generate variable with incrementation

Tags: php, variables, dynamic

I want to increment a variable in a loop. To do this, I created a variable I incremented each turn.

I have tried many methods such as the one presented below but nothing works... Thank you. Thank you.

```
    <?php 
    $i = 1;
    while($i < 16):?>

    <tr id="<?= $i; ?>" >
        <td class="hidden-xs"><?= $expenses += $i['name']; ?></td>
        <td class="hidden-xs"><?= $expenses += $i['price']; ?> &euro;</td>
    </tr>

    <?php 
    $i++;
    endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: Where are you getting `$i['name']` from?

Comment: Oh.. i think its an error.. i just want to display "echo $expenses_1['name']; echo $expenses_2['name']; ...."

Comment: Why name your variables like this? Use associative array instead.

Comment: I edit my reply, i write a mistake

Answer (score 0):

A couple of points to clear up things:

1. In php you concatenate strings by using the `.` or `.=` operators
   and not the `+=` operator. The latter one only adds up numerical
   values of variables.
2. You cant concatenate variable names and expect them to act as another variable. Eg: expecting $expenses.$i to somehow translate to
   $expenses_1. What you are doing by using the `.` operator is
   concatenate variable **values** and not its **name**.
3. If you wish to iterate over a list of variables each named differently its more convient to make an array with the variables
   values all included and well structured.

To answer your specific question:
Use an array of arrays to store all the information:

```
<?php 
$expenses = [0 => ['name' => 'ExpenseName1',
                   'price' => 'ExpensePrice1'],
             1 => ['name' => 'ExpenseName2',
                   'price' => 'ExpensePrice2'],
             2 => ['name' => 'ExpenseName3',
                   'price' => 'ExpensePrice3'],
             3 => ['name' => 'ExpenseName4',
                   'price' => 'ExpensePrice4'],
             4 => ['name' => 'ExpenseName5',
                   'price' => 'ExpensePrice5']];
$i = 0;
while($i < 5):?>

<tr id="<?= $i; ?>" >
    <td class="hidden-xs"><?= $expenses[$i]['name']; ?></td>
    <td class="hidden-xs"><?= $expenses[$i]['price']; ?> &euro;</td>
</tr>

<?php 
$i++;
endwhile; 
?>
```

Which gives you:

```
<tr id="0" >
    <td class="hidden-xs">ExpenseName1</td>
    <td class="hidden-xs">ExpensePrice1 &euro;</td>
</tr>

<tr id="1" >
    <td class="hidden-xs">ExpenseName2</td>
    <td class="hidden-xs">ExpensePrice2 &euro;</td>
</tr>


<tr id="2" >
    <td class="hidden-xs">ExpenseName3</td>
    <td class="hidden-xs">ExpensePrice3 &euro;</td>
</tr>


<tr id="3" >
    <td class="hidden-xs">ExpenseName4</td>
    <td class="hidden-xs">ExpensePrice4 &euro;</td>
</tr>


<tr id="4" >
    <td class="hidden-xs">ExpenseName5</td>
    <td class="hidden-xs">ExpensePrice5 &euro;</td>
</tr>
```